# Extends layout in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a problem with laravel layouts.
So I have in views/layouts/main.blade.php one yield('content')
Now I want to extend this layout : views/categories/index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
```

But I have an error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_PARSE)

syntax error, unexpected 'extends' (T_EXTENDS)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also have `@stop` after `@section`. Also, in the layout you should have `@yield('content')`.

Comment: I have an yield('content') and a stop for section men

Comment: I found the error : I started file by <?php ), sorry

Comment: Hah. Habit, I guess, no? I'm glad you fixed it.